# Trouble with operator < overloading in C++

Tags: c++, set, operator-overloading

I'm just learning operator overloading and am trying to add two vertices of my custom class to a set.  This causes strange errors and my attempt at `<` overloading didn't work.

Can someone explain what's wrong?

My `Vertex` class:

```
class Vertex{                                                   
public:
    int i, j; 
    set<Vertex> adj; //adjacent vertices

    Vertex(){
        i = j = -1;
    }
    ~Vertex(){
        adj.clear();
    }
    //end constructors and destructors

    void setPos(int row, int col){
        i = row;
        j = col;
    }//end setPos()

    /** must overload for set<Vertex> to function */
    bool operator < (const Vertex &o){
        if(i < o.i) 
            return true;
        if(i > o.i)
            return false;
        return j < o.j; 
    }

};//END class Vertex
```

But calling this function in main causes strange output in terminal and an error:

```
/** connect v1 and v2 such that they are adjacent */
void addEdge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2){
    v1.adj.insert(v2);
    v2.adj.insert(v1);
}//END addEdge()
```

Error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:48:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_cla
sses.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from FileMaze.cc:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h: In instantiation
 of 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = V
ertex]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:1321:11:   required f
rom 'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*> std::_Rb_tree
<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(const key_
type&) [with _Key = Vertex; _Val = Vertex; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<Vertex>;
 _Compare = std::less<Vertex>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Vertex>; std::_Rb_tree<_K
ey, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = Vertex]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h:1374:47:   required f
rom 'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val>, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _Ke
yOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = Vertex;
_Val = Vertex; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<Vertex>; _Compare = std::less<Vertex
>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Vertex>]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_set.h:463:29:   required fro
m 'std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare,
typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Com
pare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = Vertex; _Compare = std::le
ss<Vertex>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Vertex>; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key,
std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_ite
rator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Vertex>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::
value_type = Vertex]'
FileMaze.cc:47:18:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:235:20: error: pa
ssing 'const Vertex' as 'this' argument of 'bool Vertex::operator<(const Vertex&
)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
```

make: *** [FileMaze.o] Error 1

Comment: "and an error" is not useful to us unless you tell us **what** error it is. (BTW, your `<` operator should really be `const` if you want to write in good style…)

Comment: What output? What error?

Comment: Edited to show error.

Comment: You probably want to store pointers to `Vertex` in `adj` and pass parameters to`addEdge` by reference. Read up on C++ value/reference/pointer semantics.

Comment: Mark the operator override as `const`.

Comment: `operator <` should be a const method.

Comment: (Off-topic) Your data structure is not suitable for representing cyclic graphs. (On topic) The operator must be `const` it you want to use your class in `std::set`.

Comment: @cmbasnett operator overload not override

Comment: @n.m. could you explain what you think is wrong with its representation for a cyclic graph?

Comment: Your vertex contains *copies* of adjacent vertices which contain copies of their adjacent vertices which...

Comment: @n.m. It is worse than that. The class is actually only suitable for *undefined behaviour*, since it contains a container of an incomplete type. Greg, you should look up "boost containers of incomplete types", but I think you need containers with reference semantics anyway.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. and @juanchopanza!  Coming from Java so this isn't immediately apparent to me.

Answer (score 2):

The `operator<` function needs to be a `const` member function. Change it to

```
bool operator < (const Vertex &o) const;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check [this page of c++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-member-fns.html).

In fact when you overload functions like `Less operator`, you don't change the objects and so It is expected that to be overloaded as `const member function` :

```
bool operator < (const Vertex &o) const {
                                  ^~~~~
    }
```